# Node.js: JSDOM removes inline events

Tags: javascript, dom, node.js, jsdom

When using the JSDOM module on raw html, it removes any trace of inline events. I'm not sure why it would do this so arbitrarily.

Did anyone find a way to get around this or is it something i'm doing wrong?

Example:

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
jsdom.defaultDocumentFeatures = {
    FetchExternalResources   : false,
    ProcessExternalResources : false,
    MutationEvents           : false,
    QuerySelector            : false
};

var body="<a onclick='foo();'>FOO</a>";
var window = jsdom.jsdom(body).createWindow();
console.log(window.document.innerHTML);
```

This code would output

```
<a>FOO</a>
```

Comment: "is it something i'm doing wrong?" Your using inline events, this is doing it wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this has been fixed as of jsdom 0.2.8